# This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get posts (public data) from a page where one of the app testers is an admin, the app is still in development, as we read in the docs that Page Public Content Access is available for pages where The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-content-access

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{page_id}/posts?access_token={app_id|app_secret}"
```

receives

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

What are we missing? does it makes a difference if the tester(who is the admin of the page) is the one who generates the app token (app_secret)? or it is the same regardless?

Comment: _“as we read in the docs that Page Public Content Access is available for pages where …”_ - no, it is not available for those, it is not _necessary_ for those. But you need to use a page access token in your request, and not an app access token, like you are currently trying to do.

Comment: ok but I won't have access to page token unless the user who has a role in the page grants permission which shouldn't be the case when we are trying to get public data.

Comment: Then you have to submit your app for approval of this feature first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-content-access

Comment: ok, will do then. I thought I need to have a verification of a working app before submission but as I can't develop without it i guess i ll have to see what they have to say about it

Comment: @ma7555 Did you get any response from Facebook on this? Running into the same issue, and can't find a way to test the API without submitting the app.